# doubeling the content in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Rails 4, Ruby 2

I want to count the downloads on my site.

The first task works:

```
def download_many # select checkboxes and make a zipfile out of it
require 'net/ftp'
... #open ftp connection and create zipfile

     params[:files].each do |filename|
       File.open("path/to/download_log.txt", "a"){|l| l << "#{params[:file]}\n"} 
       #getbinaryfile from ftp server and add to zipfile
     end #do

     #send zipfile to user
...
end #def
```

`[:files]` gives me an array with the file names. I add a new line to the log file containing that name in order to make a simple counter for all the files

However

```
def download #download one file per directly clicking on it
require 'net/ftp'
... #open ftp connection

   File.open("path/to/download_log.txt", "a"){|l| l << "#{params[:file]}\n"} 

... #send file to user
end #def
```

doesn't work. It adds the file name twice! to download_log. params[:file] is the file name as a string.(Only returned once, i tested this with `puts params[:file]`) I know i could work with a database to store my statistics. But the encountered behaviour troubles me ...

Any explanation for this? Where could i find logs or hints to get nearer to the problem?

Comment: is it possible that on the one file click the first method is also been executed?

Comment: @Mindbreaker: Thanks for your hint. I did call the action once, but the line to add to the log twice. I still don't know why and how. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: I think you might like to learn some debugging techniques for a rails application: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/